# Downloading entire dataset from FTP and using the specific files with regex for data manipulation in R

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, ftp, data-manipulation

I have the following public dataset on FTP. I want to download the entire HistoricalOffers folder from it. After downloading the entire folder I wish to use only the files in every folder that starts with the format "DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-<12 digits>.csv". Below is the code that I was using but have been unsuccessful in getting the desired result.

```
library(curl)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
link = "ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/HistoricalOffers/"
handle = new_handle(dirlistonly=TRUE)
conn = curl(link, "r", handle)
tbl = read.table(v, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, fill=TRUE)
close(v)
tbl
```

This is displaying the files in R but I wish to download the entire "HistorialOffers" folder for future use and then wish to extract files having names with the above mentioned format. I took reference from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645445/downloading-files-from-ftp-with-r).

I know for getting the files with the names having a specific format I need to use regex for which I tried this with no success -

```
filenames = list.files(path="ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/HistoricalOffers/2014", pattern="^[DA-OR-OFFERS-]/d.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
content.list <- lapply( filenames, function(x) fread( x, sep = "\n", header = FALSE )[grepl( pattern, V1 )] )
```

I am getting this error while running the above code for applying regex -

```
Error in list.files(path = "ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/HistoricalOffers/2014",  : invalid 'pattern' regular expression
```

I also tried referring some regex cheatsheets online but couldn't figure out what the correct pattern would look like. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Link to dataset - [data](ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/HistoricalOffers/)

Additional Info - Some examples of file names => DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-201403010100.csv, DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-201403020100.csv, DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-201403030100.csv

Comment: Try `pattern="^DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-\\d{12}\\.csv$"` or `pattern="^(.*/)?DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-\\d{12}\\.csv$"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-\d+.csv
```

Like so:

```
list.files(path="ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/HistoricalOffers/2014", pattern="DA-ENERGY-OFFERS-\d+.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

As shown here: **https://regex101.com/r/cYM9lT/2**

As for what error your code had, you were using character classes wrong. `[...]` matches one of the characters within `[]`, not the entire string. Example: `[abcd]` will match each individual character in it i.e. 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd'

Using it with a `-` implies **any character within that range**
Example: `[a-h]` will match every individual character within the range of 'a' and 'h' (inclusive). In your code, when the regex encounters `R-O` within the character class, it's confused because there is no valid answer for `R-O`. Hence, the error in the pattern.