# R import csv files from FTP Server to data-frame

Tags: r, import, ftp

I am trying to import csv-files from a ftp server to R.
It would be best to import files into a `dataframe`.
I want to import only specific files from ftp server, not all of the files.
My issues began by trying to import only one file:

```
url <- "ftp:servername.de/"  
download.file(url, "testdata.csv")
```

I got this error message:

```
try URL 'ftp://servername/'
Fehler in download.file(url, "testdata") : 
can not open 'ftp://servername.de/' 
Additional Warning
In download.file(url, "tesdata.csv") :
URL 'ftp://servername/': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
```

Another way I tried was:

```
url <- "ftp://servername.de/"
userpwd <- "a:n"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd
                ,ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE
                )
```

Here I do not understand how to import the files into an R-Object.
Additionally, it would be great to get a clue on how to handle this process with zipped data instead of csv-data (format: .gz)

Answer (score 1):

Use the curl library to extract the directory listing

```
library(curl)
url = "ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2015/11/PXD000299/"
h = new_handle(dirlistonly=TRUE)
con = curl(url, "r", h)
tbl = read.table(con, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
close(con)
head(tbl)
                                                 V1
1  12-0210_Druart_Uterus_J0N-Co_1a_ORBI856.raw.mzML
2  12-0210_Druart_Uterus_J0N-Co_2a_ORBI857.raw.mzML
3  12-0210_Druart_Uterus_J0N-Co_3a_ORBI858.raw.mzML
4 12-0210_Druart_Uterus_J10N-Co_1a_ORBI859.raw.mzML
5 12-0210_Druart_Uterus_J10N-Co_2a_ORBI860.raw.mzML
6 12-0210_Druart_Uterus_J10N-Co_3a_ORBI861.raw.mzML
Paste the relevant ones on to the url and use
urls <- paste0(url, tbl[1:5,1])
fls = basename(urls)
curl_fetch_disk(urls[1], fls[1])
```

Reference:

[Downloading files from ftp with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645445/downloading-files-from-ftp-with-r)

Comment: Now I don't know how to pass username and password in this curl request curl::curl_fetch_disk(urls[1], fls[1])? I got errormessage; error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(urls[1], fls[1]) : Access denied: 530